# I have a resolution problem

Tags: display-resolution

I have just installed ubuntu 14.04.3 on my laptop.It had win xp and I wanted to try something more different than windows.So I installed the os and my max resolution is 640x480 and my laptop is 1280x800.It's a Fujitsu Siemens Esprimo mobile v5535.I had another os problems on windows but I solved them really easilly.

Any help would really be useful.

Comment: There are a couple of places that will get you started: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Monitor_or_Screens and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto . If you can't fix it yourself, please do come back and add your video card. My 2003 ex-Win XP desktop had the wrong resolution after installing Lubuntu 14.04 but it is fixable. Most likely you will need to create the xorg.conf file and tell your computer to use the correct driver, and/or give your screen size manually.

Answer (score 0):

To change your resolution open a terminal: Ctl + Alt +T

Find your resolution modes and ouput:
'xrandr -q'

Change your resolution to options litsed in terminal;

xrandr --output LVDS --mode 1280x800

You may  have to add a -d :0 parameter:

xrandr -d :0 -q
xrandr -d :0 --output LVDS --mode 1280x800